# std::tuple and a type cartesian_product<unsigned N_n, unsigned ... N_nm1>

Tags: c++11, math, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

The following code doesn't compile, but I don't found the error (I don't unsderstand the message error).

My basic template type, 'int_mod_N', is an integer from 0 to 'N', an integer module 'N' (to represent elements of a cyclic group). This is very easy and I have constructed a library of integers represented in radix 'B', where the digits are of 'int_mod_N', and the integer is represented as 'std::basic_strings< int_mod_N >'. It works.

The problematic thing is the type I need to represent elements of a cartesian product of 'n' sets, for each of them integers module a const integer 'N_i'.

Mathematically, I want to represent elements of **Z**_Nn x ... x **Z**_N1, only the additive group.

The next code don't compile.

```
#include <tuple>

#include "int_mod_N_t.hpp"

template<   
        unsigned N_n,unsigned ... N_nm1
    >
struct elem_set_t : 
                public
                decltype(
                    std::tuple_cat(
                        std::tuple< int_mod_N_t<N_n> >{},
                        elem_set_t< N_nm1 ... >{}
                    )
                )
{};

template<unsigned N_n,unsigned N_nm1>
struct elem_set_t<N_n,N_nm1> :
        public
        std::tuple< 
                int_mod_N_t<N_n> , 
                int_mod_N_t<N_nm1> 
        >
{};

template<unsigned N_n>
struct elem_set_t<N_n> :
        public
        std::tuple< 
            int_mod_N_t<N_n> 
        > 
{};
```

The error message of compiler (g++ 7.2.0), is

> In file included from /tuplas_y_tipos/main.cpp:3:0:
>   /tuplas_y_tipos/elem_set_t.hpp: In instantiation of 'struct
>   elem_set_t<2, 2, 2>': /tuplas_y_tipos/main.cpp:8:20:   required from
>   here /tuplas_y_tipos/elem_set_t.hpp:10:21: error: no matching function
>   for call to 'tuple_cat(std::tuple >, elem_set_t<2, 2>)'
>          std::tuple_cat(
>          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>           std::tuple< int_mod_N_t >{},
>           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           elem_set_t< N_nm1 ... >{}
>           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>          )
>          ~ In file included from /tuplas_y_tipos/elem_set_t.hpp:1:0,
>                    from /tuplas_y_tipos/main.cpp:3: c:\mingw\include\c++\7.2.0\tuple:1575:5: note: candidate:
>   template constexpr typename
>   std::__tuple_cat_result<_Tpls ...>::__type std::tuple_cat(_Tpls&& ...)
>        tuple_cat(_Tpls&&... __tpls)
>        ^~~~~~~~~ c:\mingw\include\c++\7.2.0\tuple:1575:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   c:\mingw\include\c++\7.2.0\tuple:1572:31: error: no type named 'type'
>   in 'struct std::enable_if'    template
>   elem_set_t<2,2,2> elem;
>                       ^~~~ make.exe[1]: *** [tuplas_y_tipos.mk:97: Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1 make.exe: *** [Makefile:5: All] Error 2
>   make.exe[1]: Leaving directory '/tuplas_y_tipos'
>   ====1 errors, 6 warnings====

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend inheriting from `std::tuple` at all, and for this, you don't need to.

```
template <unsigned ... N_ns>
using elem_set_t = std::tuple<int_mod_N_t<N_ns>...>;
```

If you have some methods in mind, you should have a tuple data member, not base class

```
template <unsigned ... N_ns>
struct elem_set_t 
{
    std::tuple<int_mod_N_t<N_ns>...> data;
    // other members
}
```

Comment: Then, the member function need be normal function (externals) over the his arguments type elem_set_t, it's true?

Comment: You don't have show any members. If you have some in mind, note that *each* specialisation will need to declare them.

Comment: Sorry. If I want to have two generic element_set_t, the first that generate: n=sizeof...(N_ns), fills with 0's all positions, and other (max) elem_set_t<N_n,N_nm1...> max{N_n-1,N_nm1-1....} (it's the idea, not the code). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your two different usages interfere with each other. A 3 element `elem_set_t` will use the `elem_set_t<N_n,N_nm1>` specialisation expanding `elem_set_t< N_nm1 ... >`

Comment: The subject is that all operations are recursives. For example, to compare 2 elem_set_t, I have only compare the int_mod_N<Nn> of lhs and the int_mod_N<Nn> of rhs, and if both are equal, then compare the part elem_set_t<Nnm1...> of lhs with the same of rhs. Else I have to code the compare for  1 arg, 2 arg, 3 arg, etc.. Is not there any solution?

Comment: You only need *one* definition, the primary template, with the parameter pack. Not *three*, with partial specialisations for `elem_set_t<N_n,N_nm1>` and `elem_set_t<N_n>`